# Codeigniter: How to close fancybox and redirect the parent page

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, redirect, fancybox, fancybox-2

When login button is clicked a fancybox containing the login form appears. If the credentials are correct, I want to close the fancybox and redirect the parent page into home page. My problem is, the fancybox doesn't close and the redirecting happens inside the fancybox. Also if I chose cancel, the fancybox should close but instead an error($.fancybox is undefined) occurs. How should I fix this? Btw, I'm using codeigniter, jquery 1.10.2, and fancybox 2. Thanks in advance.

Here's my parent page:

```
<a id='login' href=<?php echo site_url('login'); ?>>Login</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#login').bind('click', function(e) {
        $.fancybox({ 
                'width': '35%', 
                'height': '40%', 
                'type': 'iframe', 
                'href': '<?php echo site_url("login")?>',
                'modal': true
        }); 
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Login controller

```
public function index() {
    $this->session->set_userdata('page', 'guest');
    $this->load->view('login_view');
}

public function checkFields() {
    $config = array(.....);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($config); 

    if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
        $this->load->view('login_view');
    }
    else{
        $userType = $this->input->post('userType');
        redirect($userType.'/home');
    }       
}
```

login_view fancybox

```
<?php echo form_open('login/checkFields'); ?>   
<div id='login_view' style='width: 30%; margin-left: 35%'>
    <div class="panel panel-default loginClass">
        <div class="fancy">
            <table class="details"  style='font-size: 14px; width:100%; margin-top: 5%'>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username </td>
                    <td><input name="username" id="username" type="text" class="form-control" required autofocus></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td><input name="password" id="password" type="password" class="form-control" required> </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><a id="forgot_pw">Forgot Password?</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <center>
                <input type="submit" id="save" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" value="Login">
                <input type="button" id="cancel" class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel">
            </center>
        </div>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#cancel").click(function() {
             $.fancybox.close();
     });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change

```
$.fancybox.close();
```

to

```
parent.$.fancybox.close();
```

or force redirect to parent page

```
parent.location.reload(true);
```

this will reload the parent page, and fancybox is closed forcely.

Comment: I also did that but it still produces this error: $.fancybox is undefined

Comment: oh that did it! How about closing the fancybox and redirecting the parent page after logging in?

Comment: specify afterClose event in fancybox initialization.                afterClose : function() { parent.location.reload(); }  this will call the reload on fancybox closing.